# Scrapy - Non-ascii-character declared, but no encoding declared

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy

I'm attempting to scrape some basic data off this site as an exercise to learn more about scrapy, and as proof of concept for a university project:
http://steamdb.info/sales/

When I was using the scrapy shell I was able to get the information I wanted using the following XPath:

```
sel.xpath(‘//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()’).extract()
```

which should return the title of the game of the first row of the table, in the structure:

```
<tbody>
     <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><a>stuff I want here</a></td>
...
```

And it does, in the shell.

However, when I attempt to put this into a spider (steam.py):

```
1 from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
2 from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
3 from steam_crawler.items import SteamItem
4 from scrapy.selector import Selector
5 
6 class SteamSpider(BaseSpider):
7     name = "steam"
8     allowed_domains = ["http://steamdb.info/"]
9     start_urls = ['http://steamdb.info/sales/?displayOnly=all&category=0&cc=uk']
10     def parse(self, response):
11         sel = Selector(response)
12         sites = sel.xpath("//tbody")
13         items = []
14         count = 1
15         for site in sites:
16             item = SteamItem()
17             item ['title'] = sel.xpath('//tr['+ str(count) +']/td[2]/a/text()').extract().encode('utf-8')
18             item ['price'] = sel.xpath('//tr['+ str(count) +']/td[@class=“price-final”]/text()').extract().encode('utf-8')
19             items.append(item)
20             count = count + 1
21         return items
```

I get the following error:

```
    ricks-mbp:steam_crawler someuser$ scrapy crawl steam -o items.csv -t csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Scrapy==0.20.0', 'scrapy')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 492, in run_script

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1350, in run_script
    for name in eagers:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 47, in run
    crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in create_crawler
    self.crawlers[name] = Crawler(self.settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 22, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.20.0-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/xxx/scrape/steam/steam_crawler/spiders/steam.py", line 18
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /xxx/scrape/steam/steam_crawler/spiders/steam.py on line 18, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I have a feeling that all I need to do is somehow tell scrapy that the characters will follow utf-8 not ascii - as there are £'s etc. But from what I can gather, its supposed to gather this information from the head of the page its scraping which in the case of this site is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Which leaves me baffled! Any insight/reading that isn't the scrapy docs themselves I would be interested in too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like you are using `“` instead of double quotes `"`

btw, a better practice to loop on all table rows would be something like:

```
for tr in sel.xpath("//tr"):
    item = SteamItem()
    item ['title'] = tr.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract()
    item ['price'] = tr.xpath('td[@class="price-final"]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: This seems so much simpler, it worked like a dream. How did you learn scrapy? Books/tutorials?